# Chart JS get actual axis-x and axis-y

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, linechart

ChartJS version 2.3 - 2.7

After playing with ChartJS for a couple of days. Is there an API that support to get the actual x,y on the line chart? Or any other ideas to have the same result?

I have tried getPointsAtEvent and activePoints but it seem to get the closest point data(s).

here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/b5bz6uuh/2/

```
type: 'line',  data: {
labels: ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"],
datasets: [
    {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    borderWidth: 1
    },  
        {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]  }
```

and wondering if I can get something like this below
[image]